# How to use Restrict attribute in service stack

Tags: servicestack

Is there any documentation on use of `[Restrict]` attribute with service stack?

Not finding any documentation, I started trying to figure this out.  I discovered you have to enable restrictions in AppHost.cs Configure event with

```cs
var endpointHostConfig = new EndpointHostConfig
        {
            EnableAccessRestrictions = true,
        };
```

Then I added attributes to my request DTO:

```cs
[Route("Hello/World", "GET")]
[Restrict(EndpointAttributes.InternalNetworkAccess)]
```

This does not work...looks like that removes all 'default' restrictions and replaces it with just that one restriction?   Using this instead seems to work:

```cs
[Restrict(InternalOnly = true)]
```

When I do a GET from the local lan it works, but from remote it does not.  Interesting, the 'detailed stack error' it gives from remote is:

> The following restrictions were not met: '\n -[InternalNetworkAccess, Secure, HttpHead, HttpPost, HttpPut, HttpDelete, 
>   HttpOther, OneWay, Soap11, Soap12, Xml, Jsv, ProtoBuf, Csv, Html, Yaml, MsgPack, FormatOther, AnyEndpoint]'

Note, it does not even list HttpGet as one of the possiblities - which does work.  Also mentions Secure and not InSecure...neither of which I am specifically requiring.

Can we get some clarification on exactly how this is supposed to work?  What if I wanted to require SSL - how would I specify that?

What if I wanted to require SSL in production, but not staging on all services for this endpoint?  (Realizing this may be a completely different way to configure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[Restrict]` attribute feature is in the latest version of ServiceStack. Currently the only documentation for this exists in the [Security wiki page](https://docs.servicestack.net/auth-restricting-services).

Here are some [EndpointAttributes restrictions tests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/EndpointRestrictionTests.cs) that test the validation of the restriction attributes, and some [different service configurations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.IntegrationTests/Services/EndpointAccessService.cs) you can use.

The way it works is that it's restricted to anything that's specified, so if you want to enable SSL and leave everything else as unrestricted, you would only add:

```
[Restrict(EndpointAttributes.Secure)]
public class SslOnly { }
```

It also supports specifying multiple combinations of environments that are allowed, e.g. You can enforce HTTP internally, but HTTPS externally with:

```
[Restrict(EndpointAttributes.Secure   | EndpointAttributes.External,
          EndpointAttributes.InSecure | EndpointAttributes.InternalNetworkAccess)]
public class SslExternalAndInsecureInternal { }
```

Note: each environment is combined with Enum flags and delimited with a `,`.

But it doesn't let you distinguish between debug and release builds, to enable this you would need to use C# conditional compilation symbols.

E.g only allow HTTP for Debug builds and HTTPS for production Release builds:

```
#if DEBUG
    [Restrict(EndpointAttributes.InSecure)]
#else
    [Restrict(EndpointAttributes.Secure)]
#endif
public class MyRequestDto { ... }
```

Comment: When I used [Restrict(EndpointAttributes.InternalNetworkAccess)] only, the service could not longer be called.  When I switched it to [Restrict(InternalOnly = true)] it then started working.   What is the difference?  Additionally, you misunderstand - this is not about debug/release - this is about environments.  In my config, I am defining environments and those need to alter these restrictions.  Is there a way to call restrict in the code and not use an attribute - or some way to specify environments?

Comment: Also, on the error - why are all possible restrictions that could be set returned?  Is that just saying that you did not meet whichever one of these was required?

Comment: The 2 rules should have the equivalent effect, [here's the source code](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/ServiceHost/RestrictAttribute.cs). It displays the allowed request/endpoint attributes and omits `HttpGet` and `InSecure` because that's what was used to call the service with.

Comment: I am defining environments and those need to alter these restrictions. Is there a way to call restrict in the code and not use an attribute - or some way to specify environments? Or to just conditionally set restrictions by calling the same code in my service method instead of an attribute?

Comment: There's no formal API that does this, feel free to raise a feature request in [GitHub issues](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues) and we might be able to squeeze it in the next version.